# Search Filter For Wordpress Blog Page

Tags: wordpress, post, filter, blogs

I want to create a filter by post title in the drop-down. Like https://www.yasyas.com/blogs/android-smartphone-blog

On the right side, the filter is there like that I want in WordPress.

Comment: You need a developer, this is not a page for freelancers, but page where you share some specific, coding related issues, showing some code, getting solutions ... Have you tried something at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Are you working on a wordpress admin panel now? if so..
I think here may be the answer that you want:

[image: click the Appearance and drag Categories to create a Sidebar as the link you attached]
1 click the Appearance and drag Categories to create a Sidebar ;

2 remember to give a Title to replace the Categories such as: "Post Search";

3 assign the sidebar to a Ppage that you want it to go, and go back to visit the page:

[image: the sidebar on the right is the dropdown that you want]

and I assume you know you should ONLY assign categories to Posts not Pages.

Comment: Yes I know that but I want to make a filter by post title, not the category

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer that you are looking for:
**https://firstsiteguide.com/display-category-dropdown-list/**
1 find the file sidebar.php, and change the code to the code in the link:

```
    < ? php
    $cat_id = get_cat_ID ('Sample Posts Category');
$args = array(
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    ?>
<form name="jump">
<select name="menu">
<?php
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php
endwhile;
}
?>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="Go">
</form>
<?php
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

2 then asign a sidebar to a page, then visit,should be like this: 
[image]

Comment: If I will click on go then another page will open, but I need to show the same page with a sorted result like https://www.yasyas.com/blogs/android-smartphone-blog.